# How to rotate TextView

Tags: android, zxing

I'm using Zxing bar code scanner in an application and I want to change the text in the scanner view to appear at the right side instead of at the bottom. The scanner view is set to horizontal view, i don't want to change that. I just want to rotate the textView containing the help text so it will appear on the right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't start by copying and pasting our UI. This is strongly discouraged. You should write your own scanner app, and then you wouldn't need to figure out how to change ours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a folder like this `res/anim/rotate.xml` and, give below code,

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="360" android:toYScale="0.0"
android:pivotX="40%" android:pivotY="30%" android:duration="2000" />
```

This code can be rotate your `TextView.` You can modify this. And, see this aritcle also.

[Rotating TextView Using Animation](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/tween-animation/)

Hope this can be of help you.

Answer (score 3):

A custom TextView may help you

```
public class TRotate extends TextView {

public TRotate(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(45, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

}

Comment: Tanks, that helps, but how do i implement this into the xml? I did this:

<com.google.zxing.client.android.TextViewRotator
        android:id="@+id/status_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/msg_default_status" />

but i still get a few exceptions

Comment: And what about the bounds of textview if using this approach?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to rotate text view by 45 degrees. So, here I am posting working sample.

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_discount_tag"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:rotation="315"
    android:text="1% Off"
    android:textSize="@dimen/px_33" />
```